# Handling rendering exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception, rendering

Can you explain some of the ways of handling rendering exceptions? As rendering occurs when you paint something the solution should handle proper repainting. This is not about building failure but only about rendering.

The only one I came up with is repainting. I guess there is more?

Comment: This sounds obvious, but you should write your code in a way that no exceptions can occur during rendering. Are there exceptions that you often get during rendering? Then you might have a design problem (or simply a coding error). Just triggering a repaint is not necessarily enough and might even result in an endless loop, making your application unresponsive.

Comment: What piece of code has a possibility of throwing an exception in a paint routine? If you're doing I/O in a paint routine, stop. Don't do that.

Comment: I was interested in methods of handling them out of curiosity. I have a similar problem but I posted it in another question. So basically there is no program only a thought.
Here is the other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267196/repainting-after-failed-rendering

Comment: [You should only ask *practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no generic runtime solution to this.  As Joachim notes, if you simply try to repaint there is a good chance that the repaint will trigger the same exception, and your user interface will lock up.

The best approach is to find out what causes the exceptions and fix your code so that either the root cause of the exceptions is removed, or the painting code takes the appropriate action to avoid the problem.  (The second alternative only applies if the painting code is your code ...)

---

> What if I am using a library that fails at rendering due to its bad coding or whatever?

You fix the library, or implement some kind of workaround that avoids the scenario that triggers the library failure (if that is possible).  And if that doesn't work you replace the library with an alternative that works properly.

> What if rendering fails for unknown reasons (that cannot be figured)?

Then you have a **major** problem.  If you can't figure out what is triggering the failure you won't be able to figure out a reliable remedy.  You are left with questionable / unreliable remedies ... and your application is likely to be unreliable.

> I would like to know what to do when all other systems of protection fail.

There is no way to build a reliable system from unreliable components if you cannot properly characterize the nature and/or cause of the unreliability.

---

It should also be noted that a lot of "random unreliability" in Java applications is due to inadequate synchronization; i.e. where one thread is updating some object or data structure while another thread might be trying to read it.  And most GUI-based applications are inherently multi-threaded.  If you have a library that appears to be unreliable, it *could* be that the real problem is that your application-level code is not synchronizing properly.

Comment: What if I am using a library that fails at rendering due to its bad codding or whatever? What if rendering fails for unknown reasons (that cannot be figured)?

I would like to know what to do when all other systems of protection fail.

Comment: @InvaderZim: if all other systems of protection fail, then your program fails. You **can't** protect against an unknown kind of error. That's the *nature* of unknown errors. If the library is prone to triggering a `FooException` 3 out of 10 times, then you could trigger a repaint and give up after 3 successive errors. If it's prone to trigger an `OutOfMemoryError` when called twice in 2 minutes, then you could wait 2 minutes and trigger a re-paint then. You can be arbitrarily creative, but there *is no single catch-all solution*.